# get method in Express-mongodb " Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently working in an api with mongodb-nodejs-express implementing a get method that finds all stores in my database using its id, the problem is I keep receiving the following error when I use the get method:

```
"error": "Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"
```

This is the link I'm using to prove

```
http://localhost:4005/trading/store/1124
```

This is the method I've implemmented

```
router.get('/store/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const db = await connect();
    try{
    const result = await db.collection(collection).find({ store_id: ObjectID(id)});
    res.json(result)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.toString() });
    }
})
```

This is an example of how my db looks

```
{
        "_id": "5cef828a7443855d02fc320e",
        "timestamp": "26/03/2019 18:34",
        "store_id": "1124",
        "user_id": "123",
        "product_id": "949",
        "price": "528"
    },
```

I would really appreciate any hint or help and thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: @dimitristseggenes Thank you for yor suggestion, this is the message with that modification ```{"error":"TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"}```

Comment: `console.log(result);` and post here the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strore_id is just a string. So your query should be like this:

```
db.collection.find({ store_id: id});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I'm receiving ```"error": "TypeError: db.collection.find is not a function"```, no output with ```console.log(result)``` command.

Comment: does it work for you? `const result = await db.collection(collection).find();`